# Is there way to run python unittest as multiple processes

Tags: python, selenium, concurrency, python-unittest

Is there way to run python unittest as multiple processes. I have implemented Selenium testing to my flask application but it takes very long time, I thought that running tests concurrently would decrease that time. But it's like no way that unittests can be executed by multiple processes, may be there is some workaround?

Tryed nosetests, called it like:

```
from nose.plugins.multiprocess import MultiProcess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nose.main(plugins=[MultiProcess()],
                      defaultTest=os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())), env={'NOSE_PROCESSES': 4})
```

But now some tests are skipped (actually I see output for one or two tests), but in the end of output I have line which says that zero tests was executed, why this happening? If I start just nose test in non-multiprocessing mode all tests are executed normally.

Seems to be that pytest-xdist does what I need, but process is not terminated after all tests passed, why is it happening?

UPDATE:

So I checked again and it seems that if assertions error happened then pytest is frozen after all tests are executed. But if all tests passed - then it terminated successfully what could be causing this?

Comment: I've not personally tried https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xdist but give it a shot, and pytest will run your unittests without any change to your existing suite

Comment: Ok, so I tried pytest-xdist, and it seems to be working as I wanted(concurrently), thank you. 
But I found one issue, I'm running with PyCharm and if I run tests in concurrent mode, they will be executed, but PyCharm seems to be freezed if assertation error occurs(but if I wait for some time I can see that test run is over, but PyCharm run button looks like tests are still executing), have you experienced something like that?

Comment: Everything is working thank you. Freeze problem was about wrong closing selenium driver instance. driver.quit() instead of driver.close() fixes freeze problem

Comment: Glad it worked out for you